# Primes are to Irreducible Polynomials as Prime-related theorems are to ??

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-number-theorem, ra.rings-and-algebras

Irreducible polynomials are often introduced as the analog to prime numbers in polynomial rings.  Prime numbers, of course, have a very rich theory, leading to the likes of the Riemann Zeta function and the Prime Number Theorem.

Do any analogs and/or generalizations of primes, such as irreducible polynomials and prime elements, have similarly rich theorems/conjectures?

Comment: Well, there is a zeta function and a prime number theorem for irreducible polynomials over finite fields, but both are quite easy to investigate. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the first generalization of prime numbers is to prime ideals in algebraic number fields. You do get analogs of the zeta-function, the Prime Number Theorem, even the Riemann Hypothesis. Any text on algebraic number theory will take you there.

Comment: From there on to function fields it's but a jump.

Comment: A step over a curb type jump or an Evel Knievel Snake River Canyon-like jump?  Gerhard "Inquiring Minds Want To Gauge" Paseman, 2011.10.13
 